# DtSearch flag dtsSearchSelectMostRecent is based on what data

Tags: dtsearch

When using dtSearch, the search flag dtsSearchSelectMostRecent limit the result to the most recent results. I've not found the information on what data the most recent is based: the date of the document or the date of indexation.

Answer (score 1):

When selecting the documents to return (up to the MaxFilesToRetrieve limit in the SearchJob), select the most recent documents rather than the best-matching documents. Cannot be used with dtsSearchDelayDocInfo, because the document date for each document is needed.